# multiple java's TimeZone's are directed to single joda's DateTimeZone

Tags: java, timezone, jodatime

I work with joda's DateTimeZone's and all its features.

I get a java standard TimeZone from a 3'rd party.

I then convert it to DateTimeZone as follows:

```
TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone(3rd_party_timezone_string_id);
DateTimeZone dateTimeZone = DateTimeZone.forTimeZone(timeZone);
```

I noticed that several timezones are mapped to the same DateTimeZone. For example:

"Australia/Adelaide" --> "Australia/Adelaide"

"Australia/South" --> "Australia/Adelaide"

I wonder, then, when I have the DateTimeZone, how can I get a list of the TimeZone's mapped to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you get the time zone data and code from IANA ([`tzcode`](http://www.iana.org/time-zones/repository/releases/tzcode2014j.tar.gz) and [`tzdata`](http://www.iana.org/time-zones/repository/releases/tzdata2014j.tar.gz) as of 11/11/2014), inside `tzdata` you can find a `backward` file that provides links between current names for time zones and their old names.

For example, in that file you can find the one you mention:

```
(...)
Link    Australia/Adelaide  Australia/South
(...)
```

If you want to have such "map" of IDs, you can iterate through available IDs and get the current name with `DateTimeZone.forID()`.

This little script in groovy makes what you want (you can easily port it to java):

```
@Grapes(
    @Grab(group='joda-time', module='joda-time', version='2.5')
)

import org.joda.time.*
import org.joda.time.format.*

Map<String, List<String>> equivalentZones = new HashMap<String, List<String>>()

DateTimeZone.getAvailableIDs().each { id ->
    DateTimeZone dtz = DateTimeZone.forID(id)
    zonesForID = equivalentZones.get(dtz.ID, [])
    if (id != dtz.ID) {
        zonesForID << id        
    }
    equivalentZones.put(dtz.ID, zonesForID)
}

equivalentZones.each { k,v ->
    println "$k -> $v"
}
```

It yields:

```
(...)
Africa/Maputo -> [Africa/Blantyre, Africa/Bujumbura, Africa/Gaborone, Africa/Harare, Africa/Kigali, Africa/Lubumbashi, Africa/Lusaka]
(...)
Asia/Shanghai -> [Asia/Chongqing, Asia/Chungking, Asia/Harbin, PRC]
(...)
Australia/Adelaide -> [Australia/South]
(...)
Europe/London -> [Europe/Belfast, Europe/Guernsey, Europe/Isle_of_Man, Europe/Jersey, GB, GB-Eire]
(...)
```